# Deleting a google calendar event with python - getting Event ID

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have recently followed the python quick start guide for python here:

```
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python
```

And have successfully added some objects to my google calendar.
I am then trying to delete the events, using:

```
service.events().delete(calendarId='primary', eventId='eventId').execute()
```

While this would ideally work, I can't find a way to get the event ID of any of my events. How am I able to get/set my google calendar event Ids using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an event using:

```
insert(calendarId=*, body=*, sendNotifications=None, supportsAttachments=None, sendUpdates=None, conferenceDataVersion=None, maxAttendees=None)
```

You get to specify your own event id in the **body** section. Here is what the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.events.html#insert) says:

> "id": "A String", # Opaque identifier of the event. When creating new
>   single or recurring events, you can specify their IDs. Provided IDs
>   must follow these rules:
>           # - characters allowed in the ID are those used in base32hex encoding, i.e. lowercase letters a-v and digits 0-9, see section 3.1.2
>   in RFC2938
>           # - the length of the ID must be between 5 and 1024 characters
>           # - the ID must be unique per calendar  Due to the globally distributed nature of the system, we cannot guarantee that ID
>   collisions will be detected at event creation time. To minimize the
>   risk of collisions we recommend using an established UUID algorithm
>   such as one described in RFC4122.
>           # If you do not specify an ID, it will be automatically generated by the server.
>           # Note that the icalUID and the id are not identical and only one of them should be supplied at event creation time. One difference
>   in their semantics is that in recurring events, all occurrences of one
>   event have different ids while they all share the same icalUIDs.

You can store this id and later use it to delete the event.

The body could be as follows:

```
{
    "attachments": [ 
      {
        "mimeType": "...", 
        "title": "...", 
        "fileUrl": "...", 
        "iconLink": "...", 
        "fileId": "...", 
      },
    ],
    "creator": { 
      "self": false, 
      "displayName": "...",
      "email": "...", 
      "id": "...", 
    },
    "organizer": { 
      "self": false, 
      "displayName": "...", 
      "email": "...", 
      "id": "...", 
    },
    "summary": "...",
    "id": "Your ID GOES HERE", 
    "hangoutLink":"..."

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you further clarify where the id will go? I am making my "body" argument with JSON But I can't seem to put an id in there.

Comment: @MantyQ2341414514  I have added an example

Comment: Thank you for that. I have found my issue, I was trying to supply an ID in the format you posted but was not specifying one of length atleast 5 characters.